# The continuity of a certain function.

Tags: calculus

Let $\delta>0$ and $0<\varepsilon< \delta$. Set $c=\delta-\varepsilon$. Define a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by:
\begin{align*}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ $-c< x < c$,} \\
0 &\text{ $x> \delta, x < -\delta$,}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
while 
\begin{align*}
f(x) 
&= \frac{1}{\lambda_1} \int_{-\delta}^{x} \exp\left( \frac{1}{(y+\delta)(y+c)} \right) \text{d}y, \quad \text{ for } -\delta \leq x \leq -c,
\\&= \frac{1}{\lambda_2} \int_{x}^{\delta} \exp\left( \frac{1}{(y-\delta)(y-c)} \right) \text{d}y, \quad \text{ for } c \leq x \leq \delta,
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 = \int_{-\delta}^{-c} \exp\left( \frac{1}{(y+\delta)(y+c)} \right) \text{d}y \quad \text{ and } \quad
\lambda_2 = \int_{c}^{\delta} \exp\left( \frac{1}{(y-\delta)(y-c)} \right) \text{d}y.
\end{align*}
How can i prove that $f$ is continuous on $(-\delta,-c)$. I appreciate any help. It seems that we must use the Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be obvious that we have our issues as $x$ approaches $\pm\delta$ and $\pm c$

At each of the critical points we need to show that:

$\lim_\limits{x\to \delta^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to \delta^-} f(x)$ (or similar)

$\lim_\limits{x\to \delta^+} f(x)  = 0$

$\lim_{x\to \delta^-} f(x) = \lim_\limits{x\to\delta -} \lambda_2 \int_x^{\delta} \exp(\frac{1}{(y-\delta)(y-c)})\ dy$

$\exp(\frac{1}{(y-\delta)(y-c)})$ has a maximum at $y = \frac{\delta - c}{2}$ and is symmetric about this line.

And $0\le \exp(\frac{1}{(y-\delta)(y-c)})$ for all $y$ in $[c,\delta]$

if $\frac{\delta - c}{2} <x < \delta$

$\lambda_2 \int_x^{\delta} \exp(\frac{1}{(y-\delta)(y-c)})\ dy < (\delta - x)$

$\lim_\limits{x\to\delta -} f(x) = 0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Now say something similar about the other critical points.

Comment: Ok, this is fine. Can I ask you another question please?